# How to directly write to summary which mimics scalar_summary?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I would like to achieve something like `scalar_summary`, but not used as a `Op` that takes a `Variable`. E.g. If I call

```py
for i in 10000:
    value = 0.2 * i
    myfun(tag, value, i)
```

In tensorboard events I expect it generates a plot named tag, with a line in it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Alternatively, if you want to generate a TensorBoard log in pure Python code, you can do the following:

```py
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(log_dir)
for i in 10000:
    value = 0.2 * i
    summary = tf.Summary(value=[tf.Summary.Value(tag=tag, simple_value=value)])
    summary_writer.add_summary(summary, global_step=i)
summary_writer.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no requirement that the argument to `scalar_summary` is a `Variable`. It just needs to be a `Tensor`. You could make `value` a placeholder and feed many different values of it in inside your for loop.

Comment: I have got to run summary op for each fed value, right?